# What is the X-Parse-REST-API-Key in parse REST API?

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to host the opensource parse-server on heroku.

The opensource documentation (https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#users) says that for all the REST APIs, there should be a X-Parse-REST-API-Key.

E.g. User Login.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'username=cooldude6' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=p_n7!-e8' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

I am not very sure what is the REST-API-KEY? In fact, the APi will work without the REST-API-KEY:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'username=cooldude6' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=p_n7!-e8' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/login
```

Is this a mistake in the documentation or did I miss out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source documentation is quite outdated. Also, most of the events does not require the REST API now. You cna just use appID and Masterkey in most cases.

Comment: looks like no much activity on the open source parse now. Not even updated documentation.